# Does anyone else uses Quest Authentication services? I have an issue with startup scripts not being launched by the GPO

Tags: linux, group-policy, startup

we are using QAS 4_1_0_22 and I'm trying to launch an startup script from GPO when a computer starts.

The script is lanched if I apply it to the user, but is not launched when configured as startup script.

The machine is where it should be, the GPO is actually applied, the script is downloaded to the machine. But it never executes.

Any hint or tip?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StartUp scripts in QAS Group Policy will only run when the QAS daemon (vasd) starts.  They do not run during a policy refresh, which is every 90 minutes by default.  This can make it hard to see if your script actually ran.

You can simulate a policy application similar to what will happen when vasd starts by running the following command:

> /opt/quest/bin/vgptool apply -M startup

This should run your script and display the output.

If you decide to just stop and start vasd, you can see some information about what policies applied, using Resultant Set of Policy (RSoP):

> /opt/quest/bin/vgptool rsop

Script policies do not log their output into RSoP, but you will be able to see that the script was called.

A common user error with QAS Group Policy is that you may not have your GPO linked correctly.  Run:

> /opt/quest/bin/vgptool listgpc

And, make sure you see your GPO that contains the StartUp script is listed.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Quest support? Http:// support.quest.com

We have lots of customers using the product successfully.

Comment: That is always my second option. If somebody know and responds here, it stays documented for the community. :)